# CSS HTML on Email

Tags: html, css, email

Anybody knows why this shows up differently on a browser vs an email?
Text on image shows perfectly on the image when running it on Mozilla/chrome, but when using the same code on an email the text gets displaced below the image (right below after the image):

```
<div style="height: 260px; position: relative; text-align: center; color: white">
    <br><br>
    <img src="https://www.jquery-az.com/html/images/banana.jpg" alt="" width="400" 
      style="height:auto;display:block;" />
    <div style="position:absolute; bottom: 8px; font-size: 60px; left: 40px;">Some text</div>  
</div>
```

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Some email clients (*in fact, most of them*) do not understand **absolute positioning**.

That's why using **table-based layout** is a go-to when creating an email template.

To solve you problem I can suggest you a simple workaround – use your image as a `background-image` css property on the block and put text node as a child of this block (as I mentioned earlier, table-based layout is more preferable if you're targeting email clients).

Here is a short snippet made with table layout which supposedly will work fine and look same within most popular email clients:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="
                border: none;
                border-spacing: 0;

                width: 400px;
                height: 400px;

                padding: 8px;

                background-image: url('https://www.jquery-az.com/html/images/banana.jpg');
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-size: cover;
                background-position: center;

                justify-content: top;
            ">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td align="center" style="
                            vertical-align: top;

                            color: white;
                            font-weight: 600;
                        ">
          Some text here
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Ilya, it seems the image is not showing up any longer. Am I doing something wrong perhaps?
<div style="background-image: url('https://www.jquery-az.com/html/images/banana.jpg'); text-align: center; color: white;">
  Some text here!
</div>

Comment: not most of them. `object-position` has a support of > 65%. The only clients that can't use them are the Windows client (Outlook etc.)  that do not support unspecified HTML5 or CSS3 at all.

Comment: @JP999 The `background-image` property isn't supported by windows aswell for the same reason as mentioned above

Comment: thank you Tacoshy, any idea how to work around it? Thanks!

Comment: @JB999 The best bet would either trying `background` or use VML instead of HTML

Comment: Hello JB999, I've edited my answer and provided a short code snippet to solve you problem made with table layout which will most certainly work same in email clients. Not really sure if that's waht you actually need but i think this solution is worth trying.